# SUMIFs multiple criteria is not working consitently

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I am using Google Sheets with the spreadsheet shown below.

I want to Sum the 'Amount' column
IF the Key in column J == the key in column B
AND The Assigned person == the actual person.

So, where the key is 2, we'd have a subset of 7 items. From that the assigned person is Sally and four entries match, our total would therefore be the sum of those matching values which are 20, 10, 2, 4 giving a sum of 36.

In K3, we can correctly see the sum of 36.

The formulae I used in that cell is:
=SUMIFS(H:H,B:B,J3,G:G,D:D)

The cell below has the formulae:
=SUMIFS(H:H,B:B,J4,G:G,D:D)

So, that should, I believe sum the values 3,8 and 4 since the key (3) in column J matches three items in column B. In each case Mike is the assigned and actual person, which means we should be summing 3, 8 and 4. However, the value as you can see is 0.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, please?

[image]

Comment: Change `D:D` to `D3`, `D4`, etc.

Comment: I don't think that would work because, when we use the key with a value of '3' I can't say what the matching cell is, i.e. it's not D3 it's D10, whereas the 'key' is in J4.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question, disregard.

Comment: No problem. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Use SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this with a single formula in Google Sheets;

```
=query(B2:H," select B,sum(H) where D=G and B is not null group  by B label sum(H) ''")
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know I could do queries in Google Sheets. That worked perfectly, thank you so much. :)

Comment: Glad it was useful

Answer (score 2):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$13=J2)*(D$2:D$13=G$2:G$13)*H$2:H$13)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me on Google Sheets. I tried removing the $ and I am still getting 0 in each case.

Comment: The `$` are necessary to lock the ranges so that they don't change as you drag the formula down. There should not be any `$` in `J2` though, that needs to update to `J3`, `J4`, `J5`... as you drag.